# Question regarding algebraic multiplicity and eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra

I am a bit stuck on a multiple choice question and was hoping for a little guidance.

The question states:

**Let A be a 4x4 matrix with the first eigenvalue = 1 (algebraic multiplicity 3) and the second eigenvalue = 2. Which of the following are true:**

*a)The homogenous system of linear equations AX=1X has only the trivial solution*

*b)The geometric multiplicity of the first eigenvalue = 3*

I've just written out the ones I'm having trouble with.

My first question, in my book it states a nxn matrix is diagonalizable if it has n distinct eigenvalues. I assume this means that in the case of my question above, for my 4x4 matrix to be diagonalizable, it must have 4 distinct eigenvalues, but it does not because 1 is repeated three times, so from this I got that matrix A is not diagonalizable.

This is why I figure part b) is false because for the algebraic multiplicity to equal geometric multiplicity, the matrix must be diagonalizable which it is not. So the geometric multiplicity can't be 3 or more, but can be 1 or 2? Is my thinking correct or have I gone wrong in my theories?

For part a), I am a bit more confused. I assume AX=1X only has a trivial solution if the geometric multiplicity of the first eigenvalue is 1? However, how am I to know that it isn't 2? All I know from the fact that the matrix isn't diagonalizable is that the geometric multiplicity is not 3 or more.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$4$ distinct eigenvalues is a *sufficient* condition to be diagonalisable, but it is by no means a *necessary* conditions. For instance, $I_4$, the unit matrix in dimension $4$, has only $1$ as an eigenvalue, with multiplicity $4$, yet it is a diagonal matrix.

For $b)$, all we can conclude is the geometric multiplicity of the first eigenvalue is *at most* $3$. It is $3$ if and only if it is diagonalisable. For instance, these matrices are not diagonalisable:
$$\begin{bmatrix}1&1&0&0\\0&1&1&0\\
0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&2\end{bmatrix}\qquad\begin{bmatrix}1&1&0&0\\0&1&0&0\\
0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&2\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: so how can i justify whether c is correct or not?

Comment: I'd love to help, but *what* is c?

Comment: Oh! Very sorry I meant part b) of my original question.  "b)The geometric multiplicity of the first eigenvalue = 3" I'm not sure how I can determine what the geometric multiplicity of the eigenvalue 1 will be having been given  that it's algebraic multiplicity is 3

Comment: The geometric multiplicity can be $1$, $2$ or $3$. It is diagonalisable if and only if it's $3$. For the matrices I posted, the geometric multiplicities are respectively $1$ and $2$.

Comment: Hm I understand that the geometric multiplicity of my eigenvalue 1 could be 1, 2 or 3. What I don't get is why in the solutions posted for this question it states that b) is false because the geometric multiplicity is only 3 if A is diagonalizable. How did they conclude that A is not diagonalizable?

Comment: You misunderstood: b) is false because you cannot prove it is is diagonalisable from this sole information. In other words: the geometric multiplicity may or may not be $3$.

Comment: Oh! I see they are saying it is false because there is not enough information to tell. That makes it much more clear, thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

A) is false because being an eigenvalue implies it has a non trivial solution.

Comment: So there can't be a case where an eigenvalue has only the 0 eigenvector as a solution?

Comment: No, being an eigenvalue means it has a nonzero solution, that's the definition.

Comment: Thank you!! That makes it clear now! Would anyone be able to clarify this statement and my reasoning?  "In my book it states a nxn matrix is diagonalizable if it has n distinct eigenvalues. I assume that in the case of my question above, for my 4x4 matrix to be diagonalizable, it must have 4 distinct eigenvalues, but it does not because 1 is repeated three times, so from this I got that matrix A is not diagonalizable."  Is any part of this incorrect? Thanks again!